# Docker container communication on the same net not work

Tags: docker

I have 3 different docker container (on windows 10) on the same network (core_net), but when use curl on backend

```
-curl localhost:7000
```

the response is:

"curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7000: Connection refused"

Why?

Docker commands:

Frontend:

```
docker run -itd --name dam --net=core_net -p 3000:3000 DAM
```

Backend:

```
docker run -itd --name core --net=core_net -p 6000:6000 -p 7000:7000 -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 SG
```

Database:

```
docker run --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:3
```

These is the dockerfile:

```
Frontend:
FROM node:4.5.0
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /DAM
WORKDIR /DAM

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /DAM
RUN npm install
RUN npm install gulp -g
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc
RUN npm install bower -g

# Bundle app source
COPY . /DAM

ENV PORT 3000 3001
EXPOSE  $PORT

CMD ["gulp", "serve"]
```

and

```
Backend:
FROM node:4.5.0

RUN npm install nodemon -g

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /SG
WORKDIR /SG

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /SG
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /SG

ENV PORT 6000 7000 8000 9000
EXPOSE  $PORT

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Inside container the ping works and the inspect is this:

```
$ docker network inspect core_net                                                                               

   {                                                                                                       
       "Name": "core_net",                                                                                 
       "Id": "1f9e5426abe397d520360c05c95fee46fe08c98fe5c474c8b52764e491ea23e7",                           
       "Scope": "local",                                                                                   
       "Driver": "bridge",                                                                                 
       "EnableIPv6": false,                                                                                
       "IPAM": {                                                                                           
           "Driver": "default",                                                                            
           "Options": {},                                                                                  
           "Config": [                                                                                     
               {                                                                                           
                   "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",                                                              
                   "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"                                                                 
               }                                                                                           
           ]                                                                                               
       },                                                                                                  
       "Internal": false,                                                                                  
       "Containers": {                                                                                     
           "3d3b8780fba2090b1c2feaddf2e035624529cf5474ad4e6332fe7071c0acbd25": {                           
               "Name": "core",                                                                             
               "EndpointID": "f0a6882e690cf5a7deedfe57ac9b941d239867e3cd58cbdf0ca8a8ee216d53a9",           
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",                                                          
               "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",                                                             
               "IPv6Address": ""                                                                           
           },                                                                                              
           "bb6a6642b3a7ab778969f2e00759d3709bdca643cc03f5321beb9b547b574466": {                           
               "Name": "dam",                                                                              
               "EndpointID": "b42b802e219441f833d24971f1e1ea74e093f56e28126a3472a44750c847daa4",           
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",                                                          
               "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",                                                             
               "IPv6Address": ""                                                                           
           },                                                                                              
           "cf8dd2018f58987443ff93b1e84fc54b06443b17c7636c7f3b4685948961ba3f": {                           
               "Name": "mongodb",                                                                          
               "EndpointID": "be02d784cbd46261b7a53d642102887cafa0f880c8fe08086b9cc026971ea1be",           
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",                                                          
               "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",                                                             
               "IPv6Address": ""                                                                           
           }                                                                                               
       },                                                                                                  
       "Options": {},                                                                                      
       "Labels": {}                                                                                        
   }
```

Commnication between mongodb and core work but between dam and core not work.
what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

To connect to another container with in an network you can not use localhost, but cou can use the name of the conatiner you want to reach. e.g. `curl core:7000`

To use localhost the conatiners have to share their network stack. You can do that with `--network container:core`

And if you dont have to reach the backend from outside of docker, it is enought to only expose the ports, and not to publish them

Comment: yes I know...inside the container from DAM to CORE the command "curl core:7000" doesn't work and i have this error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to core port 7000: Connection refused

Comment: Try to ping core. If that works it is not an problem with the network, did you verify that node is really serving on port 7000.

Comment: the ping work...the node.js app work inside the container and also outside only the communication between core e dam not work

Comment: it's really strange problem

Comment: You dont have an multihost setup? Because then you have to use an overlay network. If not it should normally work. Maybe try if `docker network create -d bridge bridge-test && docker run -d --network bridge-test --name nginx-test nginx && docker run --rm -it --network bridge-test alpine wget nginx-test` works, because then we know it could work :)

Comment: I've already create a new network "core_net" and it share along container. Dam container has "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16" , CORE container has "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16" and MONGODB "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",  look above.

Comment: CORE work with mongodb container but not work with DAM container

Comment: Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: Solve problem...inside the node.js app I replace localhost with 0.0.0.0 and it works

Comment: Good :), but then you can also not connect from outside of the container (without the docker network) to node, because it was only available inside the container.

Comment: You Fixed it with listening on 0.0.0.0

Comment: did you read my last posts? "  
Solve problem...inside the node.js app I replace localhost with 0.0.0.0 and it works – sminodonte yesterday  " I meant that the app listening on 0.0.0.0 :-)

Comment: Yes i read it, i wrote you already Fixed it, because you asked how to resolve it, but you already habe done it. I only ment that you couldnt also reach your app from Outside what you wrote earlier